# Need assistance in understanding this code using malloc and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, types, malloc

Here is a little snippet of code from Wikipedia's article on malloc():

```
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr)); // Without a cast
    ptr = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof (int)); // With a cast
```

I was wondering if someone could help me understand what is going on here. So, *from what I know*, it seems like this is what's happening:

1) initialize an integer pointer that points to NULL. It is a pointer so its size is 4-bytes. Dereferencing this pointer will return the value NULL.

2) Since C allows for this type of automatic casting, it is safe not to include a cast-to-int-pointer. I am having trouble deciphering what exactly is being fed into the malloc function though (and why). It seems like we are getting the size of the dereferenced value of ptr. But isn't this NULL? So the size of NULL is 0, right? And why are we multiplying by 10??

3) The last line is just the same thing as above, except that a cast is explicitly declared. (cast from void pointer to int pointer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming we're talking about C here. The answer is different for C++.

1) is entirely off. `ptr` is a pointer to an `int`, that's all. It's uninitialized, so it has no deterministic value. Dereferencing it is **undefined behaviour** -- you will most certainly not get 0 out! The pointer also will most likely *not* point to 0. The size of `ptr` is `sizeof(ptr)`, or `sizeof(int*)`; nothing else. (At best you know that this is no larger than `sizeof(void*)`.)

2/3) In C, never cast the result of malloc: `int * p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);`. The code allocates enough memory for 10 integers, i.e. 10 times the size of a single integer; the return value of the call is a pointer to that memory.

Comment: But `sizeof(*ptr)` is defined and valid and the same as `sizeof(int)` even though `int x = *ptr` invokes undefined behavior. We don't know what `ptr` points to but we do know how big it should be. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, sizeof is a builtin operator that doesn't evaluate its arguments. All it cares about is the type of what is passed.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's all correct - what is this in reference to?

Comment: Just a clarification of the `malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr))` version.

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh I see, no problem. Indeed, you can use `sizeof` either with a type or an expression (in which case it means size of the type of the expression). I guess if you write `int * p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * N);`, there's less redundancy and it's easier to change the type.

Answer (score 1):

The first line declares a pointer to an integer, but doesn't initialize it -- so it points at some random piece of memory, probably invalid.  The size of `ptr` is whatever size pointers to `int` are, likely either 4 or 8 bytes.  The size of what it points at, which you'd get by dereferencing it when it points somewhere valid, is whatever size an `int` has.

The second line allocates enough memory for 10 `int`s from the heap, then assigns it to `ptr`.  No cast is used, but the `void *` returned by `malloc()` is automatically converted to whatever type of pointer is needed when assigned.  The `sizeof (*ptr)` gives the size of the *dereferenced* `ptr`, i.e. the size of what `ptr` points to (an `int`).  For `sizeof`, it doesn't matter whether `ptr` actually points to a valid memory, just what the type would be.

The third line is just like the second, but with two changes: It explicitly casts the `void *` return from `malloc()` to an `int *`, to match the type of `ptr`; and it uses `sizeof` with the type name `int` rather than an expression of that type, like `*ptr`.  The explicit cast is not necessary, and some people strongly oppose its use, but in the end it comes down to preference.

After either of the `malloc()`s `ptr` should point to a valid location on the heap and can be dereferenced safely, as long as `malloc` was successful.

Answer (score 0):

For line 2 **malloc()** is allocating enough memory to hold 10 pointers.

**malloc()** is a general purpose function **void** so it must be cast to whatever type you actually want to use, in the above example pointer to int.